# gulp and url rewrite

Tags: node.js, mod-rewrite, gulp

I have a working gulp system using browser sync that I am trying to add a proxy too to allow all API calls to be redirected to the server, unfortunately all its doing is spinning and not loading anything. I haven't tried this before so its very possible I am not doing it right, so someone with more experience might be able to spot where i went wrong.

what I am trying to do was I thought simple

all calls to localhost:3000/Mercury (get,post,put,patch,delete)

need to be rerouted to http://angular.dev.europa-sports.net:80/Mercury

here is the code for the browser-sync server part

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function () {
            browserSync({
                    server: {
                        baseDir: "../public",
                        middleware: function () {
                            return [
                modRewrite([
                  '^/Mercury/(.*)$ http://angular.dev.europa-sports.net:80/Mercury/$1 [P]'
                ])
              ];
                        }
                    }
                    });
            });

gulp.task('bs-reload', function () {
    browserSync.reload();
});
```

if anyone has any ideas on this , I would love to hear it , or if you need to see the entire gulp file let me know, this was a working gulp file until I made the change to add the modRewrite from the historyApi on the middleware

here is the original gulp task that works correctly

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: "../public",
            middleware: [ historyApiFallback() ]
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('bs-reload', function () {
    browserSync.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have completed this and figured out a nice neat solution, using gulp and browser-sync.

for those of you who use this type of system , here is the solution for proxying your api

first add this to your package.json

```
"proxy-middleware": "^0.15.0",
"url": "^0.11.0",
```

In your gulp file require the following

```
Proxy = require('proxy-middleware'),
url = require('url'),
```

Then your browser sync task should look like this, this will allow you to proxy anything coming to /api locally to go to the target destination of server.com/api
without having to configure a CORS solution.

this means that you don't have to change code to move from local to development .

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
var proxyOptions = url.parse('http://www.server.com/api');
    proxyOptions.route = '/api';
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: "../public",
            middleware: [ Proxy(proxyOptions), historyApiFallback() ]
        }
    });
});
```